# Binary Variable Regression

Tags: regression, econometrics

[image]

I am having difficulties with this question. Starting with part a). Given that we know that Beta hat 0 = ybar - beta hat 1*xbar and that beta hat 1 is equal to the covariance/variance I need to reduce it to equal the equation given for ybar 0 in the question but am having difficulties

Comment: Forget the algebra.  Focus on the concepts.  (a) and (b) say the regression line passes through the points representing the two group means $(0,\bar y_0)$ and $(1,\bar y_1)$. Find a simple argument--perhaps based on least squares--for why this must be the solution.

Comment: Im not sure if I follow. Are you suggesting that (0,Ybar0) is the solution to Beta hat 0? The question wants me to show it mathematically.

Comment: A good place to start would be the very definition of regression: the question asks you to find the expectation of $Y$ conditional on $x=0$ and $x=1$. Here's a way you can use mathematics: show that when you plug $x=0$ into equation (1) that the expectation of $Y$ is $\beta_0$. Then show that when you plug $x=1$ into equation (1) the expectation of $Y$ is $\beta_0+\beta_1$.  Now deduce (c).  You're done.